# Implementing a replacement for Ruby's IO.popen() and system()

Tags: ruby

IO.popen() and system() in Ruby is sorely lacking several useful features, such as:

- obtaining the return value of the function
- capturing both stdout and stderr (seperately and merged)
- running without spawning an extra cmd.exe or /bin/sh process

Python has a module "subprocess" which I was thinking about using as inspiration for a similar module in Ruby. Now to the questions:

- How are Ruby-programmers working around the issues above, for example obtaining the return value when doing a popen() call?
- Is this something which has already been implemented?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at the standard Ruby library [open3](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/open3/rdoc/index.html).  This will give you access to stdin, stdout and stderr.

There is also an external project called [open4](https://rubygems.org/gems/open4/), which allows you to get the exit status without using a magic variable name.

Comment: Note that for Ruby < 1.9 open3 doesn't give the exit status even *with* a global variable name - http://redmine.ruby-lang.org/issues/show/1287

Answer (score 9):

- system() exit status can be captured with `$?.exitstatus`
- stderr can be captured with something like `system 'command 2>&1'`

Answer (score 1):

I've felt the need to do exactly that when testing git_remote_branch. The tool calls out to the shell and I wanted to capture exactly what was displayed during test runs, no matter what git was displaying, and no matter if it was being spit out in stdout or stderr.

I have a module that's perfectly reusable that can be observed [here](http://github.com/webmat/git_remote_branch/tree/master/vendor/capture_fu.rb) (MIT license: use at will, just don't sue me ;-)

You can see it in action in the tests for git_remote_branch [here](http://github.com/webmat/git_remote_branch/tree/master/test/helpers/shoulda_functional_helpers.rb#L40).

Also, I've set up a repo specifically for [capture_fu](http://github.com/webmat/capture_fu/tree/master), it includes some tests and stuff. The project's not terribly well set up though. I haven't spent much time making it releasable ;-)